# How to comb/brush my cat in hard to reach areas?

Tags: cats, grooming

My cat loves being combed, he purrs and nuzzles my hands, but whenever anything, be it a comb or my hand, tries to reach his belly, he attacks it with all his four legs as soon as he notices it. Even petting his belly is tricky as I have to move from behind. When he's lying on his back, chances of petting him are nil. All my attempts with the comb have been a failure so far.

How to comb my cat's belly?

Comment: Why do you think you need to?

Answer (score 6):

Presuming that you need to do this (your cat has flea issues or is a long-haired cat with a tendency to get matted), about the only way I've found effective with this is persistence.

My technique is to start by giving the cat the preferred type of grooming until the cat is happy and relaxed, then move to the area the cat dislikes. I try to use one hand to "catch" the cat's paws so the other can reach the targeted area.

If the attack is a play/scratch my chin attack (no claws, the front legs pull your hand to the cat's chin/chest), I'll scratch and gradually lift my arm so the comb can get in and work the cat's belly (this is tricky, but can be done). If it's the protect/kill reflex I withdraw and give the cat no further attention for a while. When the cat has calmed, I'll try again starting with the preferred grooming.

This method has let me get to the belly of cats who preferred not to have their stomach touched, but it's not one I'd bother with unless there was a clear need for it.